# Could not find nmake (Compiling the inference source code of PaddleOCR)

Tags: cmake, nmake, paddleocr

I try to follow the instructions in chapter 1.3.2 https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/tree/release/2.6/deploy/cpp_infer#13.

But when I run the cmake command i always get this error.

```
$ cmake -S . -B Build -DWITH_CONTRIB=OFF     -DWITH_MKL=ON     -DWITH_MKLDNN=ON      -DWITH_TESTING=OFF     -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release     -DWITH_INFERENCE_API_TEST=OFF     -DON_INFER=ON     -DWITH_PYTHON=ON
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:25 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0026 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:28 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0104 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


-- Found Paddle host system: win32, version:
-- Found Paddle host system's CPU: 8 cores
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:46 (project):
  Running

   'nmake' '-?'

  failed with:

   Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden


CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Somebody on git hub tried it with a "." in the end but it doesn't change a thing for me.

I also checked if I added the path of cmake to the environment variables.... everything seems right. These two things where the only solutions I found...

i checked the CMakeLists File and this line causes the Error: project(paddle CXX C)

Comment: So, do you have `nmake` installed? If not, then specify another [CMake generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) with `-G` option.